# Cordova Contribute - How to push commits?

Tags: git, apache, cordova

I have just fixed a bug in the last version of Cordova ios, I would like to push my fixes to the public repository but username and password are required:

```
Username for 'https://git-wip-us.apache.org':
Password for 'https://username@git-wip-us.apache.org':
```

Where can I sign up? I have tried to use the Apache-Jira username & password but they don't seems to work.

Thank you

Comment: This link might be helpful: http://cordova.apache.org/#contribute

Comment: @PrerakSola thanks. I am following that but could not find how to register to push changes to the git repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this page](http://wiki.apache.org/cordova/IssueWorkflow), section *Providing Patches*. In case you already use GitHub, you can just send them a PR.

Comment: Thank you! I have created a patch and uploaded into Jira. After few minutes I have got a reply and the patch has been applied. Great!